# VMware on external drive

Tags: hard-drive, vmware, operating-systems

I am learning ethical hacking, and the course requires me to install VMware and multiple different operating systems inside it. I don't want to install them on my C drive, but I have a 2tb external HDD that I can use. Is there a way to keep VMware and the operating systems contained in the drive but still use it as normal?

Comment: Why do you want to install VMWare on an external, removable drive instead of your system drive?

Comment: To clarify: I am talking about the VMware software and not about the virtual machines.

Comment: Can I have VMware on the c drive but the virtual machines on the external drive?

Comment: @ArborChetia - Performance will be absolutely horrible but you absolutely can store the virtual HDD anywhere you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Workstation/Player/etc. itself is not portable.  Running VMs depends on drivers installed to the host operating system.  While you could choose an external drive as your installation directory, it wouldn't be useful since you would not be able to move that drive to another PC and power on VMs.

However, you *can* install VMware Workstation/Player/etc. to multiple PCs and store the VMs themselves (the VM's configuration file and its virtual disk files) on the external drive.  However, be aware that running a VM from an external drive could have significantly worse performance since I/O to the external drive is likely to be much slower.